# Why did my highlights turn pink/purple in Xubuntu 14.10?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, 14.10

Around the time of the start to testing of the second beta for Xubuntu 14.10, my highlights turned pink system-wide.  What gives?

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks more like purple to me ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As confirmed in remarks by Xubuntu Project Leader Simon Steinbeiß in [Launchpad Bug 1373280](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1373280), the changes can be adjusted through the use of the `gtk-theme-config` utility included in Xubuntu.  This was confirmed as **not a bug** but a deliberate design decision.

A deliberate design decision was made to emphasize the "unicorn" aspect to the 14.10 release by updating the default theme in various ways such as making the pink highlight occur even for those upgrading from 14.04 as well as for those making new installations.  In the [drafted release notes for Xubuntu 14.10 Beta 2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/Beta2/Xubuntu), the release team stated:

> *To celebrate the 14.10 codename "Utopic Unicorn" and to demonstrate the easy customisability of Xubuntu, highlight colors have been turned pink for this release. You can easily revert this change by using the theme configuration application (gtk-theme-config) under the Settings Manager; simply turn Custom Highlight Colors "Off" and click "Apply". Of course, if you wish, you can change the highlight color to something you like better than the default blue!*

Comment: Well that is very dumb, why would they do that? Made my really nice setup look ugly!

Comment: @user8951 I think it was a nice idea for a change. After all, changing it back is just a few clicks.

Comment: So whenever I will get a new new update to future releases, I have to expect to go through several configuration managers to revert some weird changes? We used to call that "Windows" in the old times?

Comment: @GuidoKanschat Joining in the work of the development allows you to make these concerns known.  Check out the how to contribute link over at xubuntu.org for more details.